# How to create dev/staging/preprod/prod and default environment using expo SDK 36 for Android iOS and Web?

Tags: android, react-native, environment-variables, expo, reactjs-native

I am using SDK36 of expo and I need to create a cross platform app for iOS, Android and the Web.

I have found that `--release-channel` will allow me different release between iOS and Android, it can be used like: `expo build:android --release-channel --staging`.

However, this option does not work for the Web, and I haven't found a way to create multiple environment for the iOS/Android/Web.

I also haven't found a way to provide configuration through environment variables to any of those apps.

This makes it almost impossible to have more than 2 env, `__dev__`, `staging`, `prod` while I need more.

Is there a way to achieve environment configuration in `react-native`?

I have tried [`react-native-dotenv`](https://github.com/zetachang/react-native-dotenv/) and [`babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables)